# Rapture of sorrow

Tags: meaning

**What is the meaning of rapture (noun) ?**
The Cambridge dictionary defines rapture as "extreme pleasure and happiness or excitement".
The Merriam-Webster dictionary defines rapture as "a state of overwhelming emotion". I have seen the usage "rapture of sorrow" in a verse in Yeat's translation of Tagore's Gitanjali:

> Days come and ages pass, and it is ever he who moves my heart in many a name, in many a guise, in **many a rapture of joy and of sorrow**.

**I suppose rapture can denote extreme form of most, but not all, emotions.** Is this assumption wrong? I feel that "rapture of anger/rage" doesn't sound correct.

Comment: I thought Yeats translated Tagore's Gitanjali. I was wrong. Tagore himself translated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionaries don't do "rapture" justice. Rapture is a very, very intense experience. The joy is so intense that parts of your mind function differently. You may lose some or all of your senses and have hallucinations. So when I hear "rapture of sorrow", I easily imagine a similar experience, but one triggered by sorrow (or rage, or any other emotion) rather than joy.

Religious people having a numinous experience describe it as "rapture". I believe this is the context for Tagore's Gitanjali.

This is poetry, however, and the normal meaning of the word "rapture" hasn't changed. Yeats chose to use it in a new way that he thought the reader would understand. I think he got it right.

Comment: I have edited my question to emphasize whether rapture can be associated with any emotion (as a matter of grammar and usage).

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my answer to address your question more clearly.